# why background image is not working in themleaf

Tags: java, html, css, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I tried with CSS to set the background image but not working in thymeleaf

I also tried with the body attribute  background Still not working..

```
body{
            background-image: url(images/uomback.jpg);
            
        }
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th=”http://www.thymeleaf.org”>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>UOM Register</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-image: url(images/uomback.jpg);

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The first think to do would be to open the `Network` tab and check if the call to get the image from `images/uomback.jpg` fails. If it fails it is important to see whether it is `404` which means you need to adjust the path OR if the code is `403/401` then it is SpringSecurity dependency that is blocking the resource fetch. Please update the question with corresponding info.